# Email configuration dynamically not changing from database in loop

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, laravel-8

I apply a foreach loop in the email configuration SMTP settings dynamically from database.there are multiple SMTP servers in the SMTP server table. I am selecting the SMTP information dynamically from the table according to `smtp_server_id` from processing table and storing it in an email configuration before sending the email on the fly. But on the first iteration, the SMTP servers that come from dB are stored on email configuration like as `config('mail.smtp.host')` but on the second iteration till the end of loop, the SMTP information do not change. The SMTP information remains the same and Mail Configuration variables remains same when they are on the first iteration. What should I do to change the SMTP configuration dynamically one one by one according to the `smtp_id` in foreach loop.

My cron job to send emails.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use App\Models\CronjobSetting;
use App\Models\ProcessingEmail;
use App\Models\SmtpServer;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEmailsBasedonDate extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sendemailviadate:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $cronJob = CronjobSetting::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->first();
        if ($cronJob->email_group_type == 1) {
            $processingEmails = ProcessingEmail::all();
            foreach ($processingEmails as $processingEmail) {
                $smtpServer = SmtpServer::where('id', $processingEmail->smtp_id)->first();
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $smtpServer->hostname);
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $smtpServer->port);
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $smtpServer->username);
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $smtpServer->password);

                $email = new SendEmail($processingEmail);
                Mail::to($processingEmail->recipient_email)->send($email);
                if (Mail::failures()) {
                    ProcessingEmail::where('id', $processingEmail->id)->update(
                        ['status' => 3]
                    );
                } else {
                    ProcessingEmail::destroy($processingEmail->id);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $processingEmails = ProcessingEmail::where('email_group_id', $cronJob->email_group_id)->get();
            foreach ($processingEmails as $processingEmail) {
                $smtpServer = SmtpServer::where('id', $processingEmail->smtp_id)->first();
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $smtpServer->hostname);
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $smtpServer->port);
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $smtpServer->username);
                Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $smtpServer->password);

                $email = new SendEmail($processingEmail);
                Mail::to($processingEmail->recipient_email)->send($email);
                if (Mail::failures()) {
                    ProcessingEmail::where('email_leads_id', $processingEmail->email_lead_id)->update(
                        ['status' => 3]
                    );
                } else {
                    ProcessingEmail::where('email_leads_id', $processingEmail->email_lead_id)->delete();
                }
            }

            return Command::SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the manager is probably caching the mail driver so it keeps using the same driver it already created ... try `Mail::purge()` after setting the config values so a new instance of the mail driver will be created (using the new configuration values)

Comment: And also please check that the compiler is not go to the of condition after sending mail. Its not deleting or update the status when email fails. Please see the code. What should I do for that. After sending mail, if mai fails means Mail::fails function its not to do any think skipping that part.

Answer (score 0):

SO I will give you two options

one: register the MailServiceProvider after new config.

```
(new \Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider(app()))->register();
```

two: creating a new Instance of swift mailer

```php
<?php

$transport = (new \Swift_SmtpTransport('host', 'port'))
    ->setEncryption(null)
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setPassword('secret')
    ->setPort($port);

$mailer = app(\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$mailer->setSwiftMailer(new \Swift_Mailer($transport));

$mail = $mailer
    ->to('user@laravel.com')
    ->send(new SendEmail($processingEmail));
```

Basically, you are creating a new Instance of swift mailer here and adding providing to laravel mailer.

Comment: Thanks sir to help me. I think the problem is same.

Comment: see the update, see if it helps

Comment: And also please check that the compiler is not go to the if condition after sending mail. Its not deleting or update the status when email fails. Please see the code. What should I do for that. After sending mail, if mai fails means Mail::fails function its not to do any think skipping that part. I want to change the status if mails fails and delete the record if mail send successfully.